# How do I make a website scroll by the viewport height with one turn of the mousewheel?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have discovered [this page](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/ext/de/highlights-2019/index.html) that has multiple images, each the size of the viewport and with just one turn of the mouse wheel you scroll down to the next.

I want to recreate this effect.

My current approach is giving the body `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` and the divs `scroll-snap-align: start;`. This gets the snapping of the elements done but you need to scroll a lot to jump to the next element.

I also tried to use `window.scroll();` with `window.onscroll` but then I realized that `window.onscroll` doesn't only get triggered by manual scrolling but also by `window.scroll();`, so this seems to not be a good approach.

Is there a way to change the amount you scroll with each turn of the mouse wheel or maybe even a better way to recreate the effect?

Comment: There is no easy solution to this. For most sites on which this is solved manually using js, it does not work too well. Your linked site, for example, is annoying to use here on Chromium, the site jumps up and down while scrolling, looking really bad. On Firefox is working without any jumping, but the scrolling with the mouse wheel is still kind of annoying. Getting this right without frustrating the visitor who wants to quickly find information is a horrible task.

Comment: @t.niese Thank you for your feedback. After this and some thoughts of my own I will consider something more user-friendly